# Corona SDK Director class error

Tags: android, coronasdk

I am developing a game in corona SDK, and I am using `director class` to change scene to scene and I get this error when i run the game on actual device but not in simulator.

**Director Class - ERROR**

> Director ERROR: Failed to execute new( params ) function on 'menu'

Why did i get this error only when i run the game on the device not on simulator?

Comment: If you can share your module where you get the error, we can help

Comment: Check the case sensitivity of your scene names, images and other resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simulator paths are not case sensitive (on Windows). Like if you write `Images/bg.png` but the path is  `images/Bg.png` the simulator may not show any error but the device filesystem is case sensitive, so it will.

Comment: I reworded this answer.  Could someone verify that I didn't make it incorrect?  (I assume the cause has to do with Linux/Android vs Windows file-system differences).

Answer (score 1):

Please read this blog post:

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/07/09/tutorial-basic-debugging/

It will show you how to read your device's console log to get any errors or warnings that are being generated by your device.  As the answer and comments above point out, 95% of the time if it works on the simulator but not on the device it's a file name case sensitivity problem.  It doesn't have to be just your images either, scene names ("menu" vs. "Menu.lua") and audio resources will also case this.